# Power Query - Detect data type dynamically

Tags: excel, powerquery, dynamically-sized-type

1 - I load one file to PQ from a specific folder.
2 - There is always just one file but it could be .txt .csv .xls .xlsx
3 - The size of the table may vary each time (# of columns)

I need the transformed table to show each column's data type.

The data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cHZsszVlwsXIeC3AjxgMemjd-leGDqH0/view?usp=sharing (not that it would matter a lot but just in case ...)

I have found this wonderful [function ] (https://gist.github.com/ImkeF/6af3d67c91b81d9eb0adceba0261a252) which does detect the data types for each column dynamically, when the table is loaded from the current workbook (table, named range).

Here is the code of the Invoked Function, when the table comes from a table in a worksheet:

```
 let
    Source = TransformColumnTypesDynamically(Data, null)
in
    Source
```

...  and works just fine.

However, for some reason when it is loaded from a text file (same data), it fails:

```
let
    Source = TransformColumnTypesDynamically(#"PC Card DAta Q1 22-23", null)
in
    Source
```

Also, if the file is loaded from a folder it fails again (here invoked to the Transform Sample File:

```
let
    Source = TransformColumnTypesDynamically(#"Transform Sample File", null)
in
    Source
```

... or if invoked for the file from Other Queries>

```
let
    Source = TransformColumnTypesDynamically(Input, null)
in
    Source
```

Thank you,

G

Comment: Load the document then call the function and apply it to the returned data

Comment: It fails if the document is loaded via folder - which I need to do. It only works if loaded via CurrentWorkbook.

Comment: Sorry that does not seem right. A table is a table. Why dont you go into home...advanced editor... and copy that, then edit your question to paste in the code you are using to process the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why your function does not work

When looking at the `TransformColumnTypesDynamically` function you are trying to use in the [GitHub Link you provided](https://gist.github.com/ImkeF/6af3d67c91b81d9eb0adceba0261a252#file-transformcolumntypesdynamically-pq), it **does not detect** the column data type, the function is just *capable to deduct it using the already detected types* of its elements.

Indeed, in the following code snippet of the function, the `Value.Type(i)` simply retrieves the type of the value in the column.

```
Types = List.Transform(Columns,
              each List.Distinct(List.Transform(List.Select(_,
              (ListItem)=>ListItem<>null), (i)=>Value.Type(i)))),
```

To be clearer, `Value.Type("1")` will return type `text` even though "1" can be converted to a number.

As a consequence,

- When you load a table from excel, the data types are already being interpreted. You can observe that the TRANSACTION_AMOUNT column elements are interpreted as numbers (which are in italics in the interface) even though the column is not explicitly converted to a number column. Then, `Value.Type` will be able to return `type number` in this context.
  [Table when loading it from an excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMAga.png)
- When you load the data from a file, all columns are being directly interpreted as text without attempt to convert them. You can observe this behaviour by looking at the ABC symbols in the column headers. As a consequence, `Value.Type` in the TRANSACTION_AMOUNT column will not be able to return the type `number` in this context.
  [Table when loading it from a file or a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfSsk.png)

## Solution

To convert data types dynamically, you can use the following function, that I found in [this Microsoft Power BI forum post](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Blog/Dynamically-Detect-Column-Types-with-Power-M/ba-p/1682639):

```
(tbl as table) as table  =>
let
    fn = (tbl as table, col as text, numberofrecords as number, marginforerror as number) as type =>
    let
        LijstmetValues = List.FirstN( Table.Column(tbl, col),numberofrecords), 
        Env = Record.Combine({[L=LijstmetValues],[DTF = #shared[DateTime.From]], [DF = #shared[Date.From]], [NF = #shared[Number.From]], [TF = #shared[Text.From]], [LT = #shared[List.Transform]], [LS = #shared[List.Select]], [LC = #shared[List.Count]]   }),
        NumberOfErrors = List.Transform({"DTF", "DF", "NF", "TF"}, each Expression.Evaluate("
                    LC(LS(
                        LT(L, each try  " & _ & "(_) otherwise ""Error""), each _ = ""Error""))", Env)),
        CheckWithinMargin = List.Transform(NumberOfErrors, each _ <= numberofrecords * marginforerror),
        typenr = List.PositionOf(CheckWithinMargin, true),  

        FirstTypeWithinMargin =  {"datetime", "date", "number", "text"}{typenr},
        CheckType = if List.Distinct(LijstmetValues){0} = null or FirstTypeWithinMargin = -1 then 4  else FirstTypeWithinMargin,
        result = Record.Field([number = type number,date = type date,datetime = type datetime,text = type text, any = type any],CheckType)
    in result,
    Columnsto2Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tbl, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(tbl), each {_,  fn(tbl,_, 7, 0.1)}))    
in
    Columnsto2Type
```

In this code snippet, the function really tries to cast each column to a datetime, a date or a number and count the number of errors to determine the final column data type.

Please note that this function may not work depending on your regional settings. For example, in France, the decimal separator is a comma (,). So `Number.From("1.1")` returns a `DataFormat.Error` for French regional settings. So, for French people, a column with the dot as a decimal separator will be interpreted as text.
You can change this behaviour by:

- changing the function to replace dots by commas (`Text.Replace("1.1", ".", ",")`) before trying to convert columns to numbers.
- changing your regional settings. To do this, go to File > Options and settings > Query Options. In the Regional Settings section, you can set the regional settings only for your workbook.
  [Changing the regional settings option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tlcq.png)

Comment: Dear Kevin, Thank you for you diagnostic and solution. Also for pointing me to the Power BI forum. Gratutude!